# How to .release() the MediaPlayer instantiated by RingtoneManager?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm getting a default Ringtone in my Activity:

```
remindRingtoneView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.remind_ringtone);

remindRingtoneView.setText(RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
            NewReminder.this, ringtone_uri).getTitle(
            NewReminder.this));
```

After this line I've got a debug line in LogCat with tag = 'Ringtone' and message =

`'Successfully created a local player'.`

When I finished Activity and system garbage collector do it's good job I got a warn message in LogCat =

```
'MediaPlayer finalized without being released'.
```

How I can release it?

Answer is:

```
Ringtone remind_ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
            NewReminder.this, ringtone_uri);        
remindRingtoneView.setText(remind_ringtone.getTitle(NewReminder.this));
remind_ringtone.stop();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your program, `RingtoneManager.getRingtone` will return an object to `Ringtone` class. If we consider this object to be `mRingTone`, then invoking `mRingTone.stop()` will release the `MediaPlayer` object.

Comment: @SergeiGrabak Thanks...  I am happy the solution worked for you

Comment: @Ganesh I was getting annoyed by this logcat message too, and eventually reached the same conclusion described here (once I finally figured out `Ringtone` was causing it). It would be nice if these things were documented!

Comment: @dlf.. I saw that you made a Q & A yourself on this issue. That's a good step !!