# Why do I occasionally see "MediaPlayer finalized without being released" in logcat even though I'm not using MediaPlayer anywhere?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-logcat, ringtone

I am, however, using `RingtoneManager` to get `Ringtone`s.

---

This information is already contained in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450255/how-to-release-the-mediaplayer-instantiated-by-ringtonemanager), but Googlers are not likely to find it unless they already know what to search for (at least I could not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `RingtoneManager.getRingtone()` internally calls `open()` on the returned `Ringtone` object. `Ringtone.open()` sets up a `MediaPlayer`, and this `MediaPlayer` does not get released unless you manually call `Ringtone.stop()`. Note that *you do not need to actually play the ringtone for this to be true*. This does not appear to be documented anywhere.

I don't know how much actual harm there is in neglecting to release a `MediaPlayer` (the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29) provides a worst-case scenario), but manually calling `stop()` on your `Ringtone`s before letting them get GC'ed will at least silence the warning.